# Calculating a convergent improper integral with infinite series diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

The integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-e^x}dx$ converges. This can be seen e.g. since $0<e^{-e^x}<1$ for all $x$ and therefore 
$$
\int\limits_0^ae^{-x^2}e^{-e^x}dx <\int\limits_{0}^{a}e^{-x^2}dx
$$
and since the latter converges, also the former, and the same for the $-\infty$ bound.

I am trying to evaluate this integral. I thought of doing a series expansion:
$$
e^{-e^x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{nx}
$$
The exponential function is analytic, so this series converges for all $x$. When plugging in, I get
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{-x^2+nx}dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2+nx}dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{\frac{n^2}{4}}
$$
but this series diverges, e.g. from Stirling's approximation, $n!\sim n^{n+1/2}/e^n = \exp\left({(n+0.5)\ln{n}-n}\right)$ and therefore this fails convergence test.

What's going on? Is there something wrong with exchanging the integral and the summation? Shouldn't this series be uniformly convergent?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the $\int\sum\mapsto\sum\int$ step. It is not justified; say, DCT is not applicable here. And no, the series doesn't converge *uniformly*. (And you've lost $\sqrt\pi$ in your calculation, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @metamorphy any idea how to evaluate the integral then?

Comment: Well, I don't think it has a nice alternative representation, let alone a closed form. For *numeric* evaluation, the plain [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Periodic_and_peak_functions) comes *extremely good* (a step of $1/25$ already gives $100$ correct digits).

Comment: (Which makes me recall my answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408406).)